# What type of power outlets are used in Bath, UK?

Tags: uk, power, bath-england

I am having a discussion about travel in the UK with some friends and I believe that in the town of Bath buildings use the same power outlets as Europe and not the UK for some reason. Can someone confirm this please and maybe give an explanation why?

Comment: Do you have some basis for this theory?

Comment: Umm, Bath in the UK uses standard UK plugs...!

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't use any electric devices in the Bath.

Comment: better ask this on skeptics :-)

Comment: Bath Plugs, on the other hand, are an entirely different thing. https://edgecastcdn.net/800034/www.perpetualkid.com/productimages/lg2/PLUG-1105.jpg

Comment: Upvoting the question because of Gilles's good answer!

Comment: upvoted for Flimzy's excellent comment, which would be turned into the accepted answer ;)

Comment: As a former resident of Bath (which, incidentally, is a [city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bath,_Somerset), not a town), I can confirm that the same power sockets are used there as elsewhere in the UK. :-)

Answer (score 20):

Bath, like the rest of Britain, uses standard British plugs with three rectangular prongs, known to a few as [BS 1363](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BS_1363).

[image: BS 1363 plug]
[image: BS 1363 socket]

If you've heard somewhere about Britain having different plugs in Bath, you (or whoever told you that) may have misheard: Britain uses different plugs in **bathrooms**. British electrical safety regulations are very tight, and normal outlets are not allowed anywhere near water. In a bathroom, you can only put [BS 4573 shaver sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#BS_4573_.28UK_shaver.29). These sockets accept European, Australian, and sometimes (if a transformer for 115V is included) US plugs.

[image: BS 4573 plug]
[image: UK shaver socket]

Electric razors and toothbrushes (but not hairdryers) sold in the UK have European two-pronged plugs. They fit in British shaver outlets and in European outlets, but not in the other outlets in a British house.

Comment: Note that UK shaver plugs look similar to Europlugs at a glance, but they are *not* the same. Most UK shaver sockets will accept Europlugs but UK shaver plugs will not normally fit in European sockets.

Answer (score 11):

As they sometimes say in those parts, "pull the other one, it's got bells on it"...

Wiring regulations in the UK are produced by the [IET](http://www.theiet.org/resources/wiring-regulations/) (formerly the IEE), as part of [BS 7671:2008(2011)](http://electrical.theiet.org/wiring-regulations/). They're the same across the whole country, and quite a few other countries copy them too.

Some international focused places may additionally offer continental or US style plugs as well (eg high end hotels), but everywhere will have standard UK 3 pin plug sockets.

[Cornwall, other other hand...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutional_status_of_Cornwall) ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Bath, UK uses the same plug as the rest of the UK.

That's really all there is to say...