# What sort of power adapter do I need to use Norwegian electronics in UK

Tags: uk, power, norway

I am going from Norway to UK for a 4 year long university course. I think the power socket is different to the one used here in Norway.

Can somebody give a link (amazon.co.uk) to the power adapter I will need to buy in order to charge my Norwegian laptop etc.

Comment: For your laptop a good solution can be a new IEC cable to the charger with the local plug on the end.

Comment: I am also taking my own Iron Press. I will still need a power adapter, wont I?

Comment: Norway/EU uses rounded power adapter plug. You will need to buy a power adapter or converter like this to use in the UK. http://www.amazon.com/Grounded-Adapter-Plug-United-Kingdom/dp/B000BMFH6Y

Comment: What additional information do you need that wasn't available from simply googling "UK power socket" or "UK adapter"?

Comment: @JoErNanO why the "security" tag?  Did you mean to add "safety"?

Comment: @phoog I am not sure. [tag:security] is for things and money, [tag:safety] is for sentient beings, according to tag descriptions. My interpretation is that the OP is afraid of frying their electronic devices as opposed to their hotel room, and therefore themselves, catching fire. What's your take on this?

Comment: @JoErNanO my take on it is that a risk of damaging an electronic device by exposing it to excessive voltage is not a question of security.  The people vs. things dichotomy is not in my opinion an accurate reflection of the different meanings of "safety" and "security."

Comment: @phoog we could discuss this on meta. Or dig out the existing question where this dichotomy must have been discussed.

Comment: @JoErNanO I came across this randomly, I know this is outdated, but I am fairly certain this word was chosen as "security" and "safety" use the same word in Norwegian - which may have caused this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [Worldstandards.eu](http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/) and [the IEC](http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/) maintain pages on the types of sockets in use around the world. The UK uses Type G almost universally (there's the odd exceptions of ["Shaver sockets" in bathrooms](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20366/what-type-of-power-outlets-are-used-in-bath-uk?rq=1) and some hotels have a strange, round 3 pin setup for lighting only). So you need something that will take your Nowergian C/F plugs and convert them to G. You'll find loads of these in airports, and in fact in stores throughout the UK, as well as plenty to be bought online.

There are a few "tricks" that travellers can use. One is that most portable electronics are USB powered these days, so buying a local (or universal) USB charger can be practical. Another is brining with them a home "power strip"/"extension cable" so they only need one adapter. You can also buy (at a slightly higher price) a variety of "universal adapters" that have different prongs to be extended for different socket types.

Be careful when buying adapters online that they are safe. See if they claim to pass any EU/UK/Other standards. If they run more than one device, they should definitley be fused. Check that the earth is continuous when it arrives if possible (doesn't matter at all for a phone charger, very important for an iron!)

Comment: Thanks very much! Will this one suffice - http://www.amazon.co.uk/Travel-Adaptor-Plug-Worldwide-European/dp/B000P0FIUM/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1442578807&sr=8-2&keywords=europe+to+uk+power+adapter?

Comment: Specific product recommendations aren't something I'd like to make, but yes, that seems to be the right sort of thing. Although buying it now from amazon UK might cost too much in shipping.

Comment: Its free shipping to UK. Its going to probably arrive around 2 days after I reach there, so that should be fine. Is the one I linked to grounded? Also is it similarly cheap to buy from the local store or airport?

Comment: I think the previous one is not earthed, so I am going with this one- http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B004TK1SKI?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=ox_sc_act_title_1&smid=ATWQPOD3N26U3

Answer (score 3):

The thing you have to watch with bringing appliances with french and german style plugs into the UK is that most readilly available "visitor" adaptors will connect the live and neutral but not the earth.

Also adaptors bought from dodgy sellers (in particular the likes of amazon marketplace) may well lack the fuse that is considered an important safety component in UK wiring.

Ideally you want an adaptor that is specifically designed for the job. These are a bit harder to find but can be found easilly enough online.

Another thing that may be worth considering is bringing a power strip with you and replacing the plug on it.